# error VSP1712 invalid .vsp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, profiling

I have generated a .vsp file that is around 4gb and I get this error when I try to open it. Does anyone know why this might be? The same thing works when I profile a smaller amount of code.

Answer (score 40):

You have probably run out of disk space. That happened to me today and that was the cause.

Comment: At first I did not believe it, but it indeed was the disk space. These report files can take up hundreds of megabytes!